# Asynchronous threading on android

Tags: android, multithreading

My question is:

> "How does the stacking work on Asynchronous threading?"
>
> For example if I call upon a new class and it gets reused for a loop
> for example would it cause a data disarrangement if they are all taken
> at different times?.

Comment: Depends on what your doing? If you have static variables that the threads are manipulating then you will definitely not have desirable results without using some type of queuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by

> if they are all taken at different times?

If you are thinking about creating multiple instances of the same AsyncTask class, then no problem, each instance will get their own thread.